# AJAX : How to manipulate variable with condition

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to find a solution to this :

- I have a  with the attribute "visibility" to hidden (this on the load() event)
- I have a button which execute an SQL operation (file called : requetesql.php)
- requetesql.php file check information in my database and return a name (the image filename).

It works very well BUT ... I would like this : When the SQL returns "nothing", the attribute style.visibility of the  doesn't change and still "hidden".

I tried many things such as :

- testing with a condition after '$('#logo').html(content);' like : `if (content==''){...]` but nothing works.

Any help will be appreciate :)

Thanks dude !

`function go(){

```
            $.ajax({


            url: "requetesql.php",
             ifModified:false,

            success: function(content) {
            $('#logo').html(content);

                document.getElementById('logo').style.visibility="visible";
                document.getElementById('logo_cont').style.visibility="visible";
                var img = document.createElement("IMG");
                img.src = 'server/php/files/'+content;
                document.getElementById('logo').appendChild(img);


        }
        });`
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have some whitespace in your return, this will remove it:

```
if($.trim(content) !==) {
  // code to handle empty return
}
else {
  // code to handle non-empty return
}
```

Comment: Good Job ! Thank you for your reply ! In fact, it was a problem with the whitespace :) Problem solved !